# session-cleanup-script not called

Tags: scripts, lightdm

Because of this [Bug](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219197) I needed to edit the `session-cleanup-script` config in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.

As [the same post suggests](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219197), adding `session-cleanup-script=/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/cleanup.sh` is enough.

But it never gets called. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this false bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=686264), which helped A LOT, the key is not to append

```
session-cleanup-script=/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/cleanup.sh
```

at the end of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` but to uncomment the `#session-cleanup-script=` line and add a value there, as position matters.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

With lightdm 1.26.0 from Ubuntu LTS 18.04.3, where there is no `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` anymore by default, I just created it. This worked for me

```
% cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[SeatDefault]
session-cleanup-script=/path/to/executable/script
```

When looking at /usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz which elsewhere is described as a template for the configuration file, there is no `[SeatDefault]`, but just `[Seat:*]`. But the latter did not work for me.